# C# SHA512 to Hex string

Tags: javascript, c#, hex, sha512

There's a javascript library called [Crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js) and i'm trying to convert some methods I use to c#.

For example in javascript:

```
 var payload = JSON.stringify({ market: "BTC-ETH", order: { price: "0.02159338", side: "buy", size: "0.024" } });
 var contentHash = cryptoJS.SHA512(payload).toString(cryptoJS.enc.Hex);
 console.log(contentHash);
```

In C#

```
 public class OrdersVM
    {        
        public string Market { get; set; }        
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Side { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
    }

 public async Task<IActionResult> Orders([FromBody] OrdersVM vm) {
     var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm);
     var contentHash = sha512Hex(payload).ToLower();
     Console.WriteLine(contentHash);
 }

 public string sha512Hex(string input)
 {
     var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
     using (var hash = SHA512.Create())
     {
          hash.ComputeHash(bytes);
          return BitConverter.ToString(hash.Hash).Replace("-", "");
     }
  }
```

`contentHash` for javascript is

> "99bb05af8aace509189e08625bb4e475a9daaafc92edf5c85fa1aefcc16c16e4533c23843c5806aef01c97e8cb4150b2dc129d04d3b6a50331833fe5cb8158fc"

and for c#

> "731b92cf482ff90ffe759e356959ec005334062bdc3c2cc78b48c3041d21a45ecaa6b33f6df2971fa868f94f04b7596e818104cb1017ed1c436365beac3a01d1"

What am I doing wrong with c# conversion?

Comment: In your C# code the properties have capital letters, in your JS code they are lowercase. Use `[JsonProperty("market")]` and so on to control how the properties are being serialized. That being said, have you checked that the JSON is exactly the same character for character?

Comment: that was exactly right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that JSON.Net, by default, will serialise your property names exactly as the appear, meaning they all start with a capital letter. There are two ways to fix this:

1. Using [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) to explicitly control the property name serialisation. For example:

   ```
   public class OrdersVM
   {
       [JsonProperty("market")]
       public string Market { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty("order")]
       public Order Order { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Use a [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) to tell JSON.Net how to process the names. Fortunately there is [one provided](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm) for you that will do this:

   ```
   var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
   {
       ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
   }

   var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vm, settings);
   ```